# How should I diagnose why my Cisco ASA denies traffic?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, security

I have a Cisco ASA, which is denying traffic from 172.16.1.5 to 4.2.2.2 on tcp/9000

How can I diagnose why this is happening from the Cisco ASA CLI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to figure out why your ASA drops traffic:

- If it's a routed ASA firewall, use [`packet-tracer`](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/29601/troubleshooting-access-problems-using-packet-tracer)
- Both routed and transparent ASA firewalls can use [`capture [NAME] asp-drop`](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/118097-configure-asa-00.html#anc13)

### Using `packet-tracer` (only on routed ASA firewalls):

Routed firewalls give us the most information when we need to figure out why something was dropped; it's best to use `packet-tracer` to figure out why the routed firewall dropped something (although it won't catch every possible case).

I'm assuming 172.16.1.5's source port is 1024 for the purposes of getting a diagnosis...  The syntax is `packet-tracer input INSIDE tcp [SRC_HOST] [SRC_PORT] [DST_HOST] [DST_PORT]`

```
asa-fw# packet-tracer input INSIDE tcp 172.16.1.5 1024 4.2.2.2 9000

!!! output truncated

Phase: 4
Type: ACCESS-LIST
Subtype: log
Result: DROP                                            <---- ASA Dropped the traffic
Config:
access-group INSIDE_in in interface INSIDE
access-list INSIDE_in extended deny ip any4 any4 log    <---- This rule denied the traffic
Additional Information:

Result:
input-interface: INSIDE
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: OUTSIDE
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: drop
Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule   <----

asa-fw#
```

---

### Using `capture [NAME] asp-drop` (routed or transparent ASA firewalls):

Transparent firewalls are trickier to diagnose, but you can still get some useful information with the `capture ... asp-drop` command.  The ASP is the ASA's "Accelerated Security Path"; this is where many drops happen.  I have seen some dropped traffic that doesn't show in `asp-drop`, but usually that's because of an overwhelmed backplane in the ASA.

There are four steps...

1. Configure a packet capture buffer on the ASA.  For tcp traffic, the syntax is `capture [CAPTURE_NAME] type asp-drop all buffer [BUFFER_SIZE] match tcp host [SRC_HOST] host [DST_HOST] eq [DST_PORT]`
2. Wait for the denied traffic
3. `show capture [NAME] trace` to understand why the traffic was denied.
4. Remove the capture with `no capture [CAPTURE_NAME]`

This is an example which shows traffic to 4.2.2.2 on tcp/9000 is denied by a configured firewall rule.

```
asa-fw# capture DENY type asp-drop all buffer 500000 match tcp host 172.16.1.5 host 4.2.2.2 eq 9000


asa-fw# sh capture DENY trace

1 packet captured

   1: 06:13:43.434761       802.1Q vlan#200 P0 172.16.1.5.33489 > 4.2.2.2.9000: S 
   884023774:884023774(0) win 14600 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 67442169 0,nop,wscale 7> 
   Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

1 packet shown
asa-fw# no capture DENY
```

When you finish, be sure to unconfigure the capture with `no capture DENY`

Comment: I fell in love with packet-tracer the moment I used it. Ought to be on every platform. The instructions on capturing ASP-Drop are quite helpful for the rest of the traffic!

Comment: Packet tracer, the solution to so many otherwise unsolved issues =).